# How to return a blank field on a row?

Tags: sql, oracle

Some aircraft components have to perform scheduled maintenance in order to maintain its reliability. But in order to be visible to the maintenance planning staff, the component PN must be in the aircraft component data base. Based on that, i have created a code that returns the aircraft that its components list is incomplete.

The code should works as follows:

1) First column = Active Aircrafts;

2) Second column = Component PN that has scheduled maintenance, from maintenance planning enviroment;

3) Third column = It counts the Nº of components installed in the aircraft;

4) fourth column = case that returns if the component is installed (case 1) or if it is not installed (Case 0)

```
SELECT B.AC,
A.PN,
COUNT (DISTINCT (A.AC)) AS "Nº OF CONTROLS",
B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES AS "TYPE/SERIES",
(CASE WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT (A.AC)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "CHECK"

FROM ODB.PLANNING A
LEFT JOIN ODB.AC_MASTER B
ON A.AC = B.AC

WHERE A.PN IN ('RCF6709')

AND B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES = 'ATR72-600'

AND B.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'

GROUP BY B.AC,
B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES,
A.PN
```

I have extracted an excel report from the maintenance planning enviroment and we have 37 active aircraft and, tanking into consideration that every aircraft must have one component pn RCF6709 installed, my code is not working because it is only returning 33 aircrafts.
That being said it is only displaying the aircraft that have component pn RCF6709 installed, but it should have been displaying also the aircraft that don't have component pn RCF6709 installed.

See the image on this link to better understand.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1-1VvWdcKXTW032IEGlX9xBO41FhmRYiV

Comment: Without sample data and current/expected results it's hard to tell... but it looks like maybe your outer join is the wrong way around, and your `where` clause is turning it back into an inner join anyway? (Your description also seems to be mixing up 'row' and 'column', which is confusing...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you need to the outer join to be the other way around - so you initially find all aircraft of the required type, and then look for optional planning records. But you also need to be careful not to accidentally convert it back into an inner join via the `where` clause.

I think this might be what you want:

```
SELECT B.AC,
  A.PN,
  COUNT (DISTINCT A.AC) AS "Nº OF CONTROLS",
  B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES AS "TYPE/SERIES",
  CASE WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT A.AC) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "CHECK"
FROM ODB.AC_MASTER B
LEFT JOIN ODB.PLANNING A
ON A.AC = B.AC
AND A.PN = 'RCF6709'
WHERE B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES = 'ATR72-600'
AND B.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY B.AC,
  B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES,
  A.PN
```

but it's obviously untested as we don't have sample data or expected results.

I'm not sure you need the `distinct` within the counts, as that value (or at least the `b` version, which is the same because of the join condition if there's a match, and the count will be zero if there isn't) is included in the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
WHERE (A.PN IN ('RCF6709') or A.PN IS NULL )
```

Comment: Please describe, what did you change and why, to help others understand the problem and this answer